# Swift String Range - Is there easier way to define string ranges?

Tags: swift, string, range

I consider if there are some easier ways to define string ranges I tried to use some function that need ranges and swift ranges seems to be incredibly unreadable and long.

```
title.startIndex..<title.index(title.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
```

and just to say I want to search only in [0,1) characters of this string

```
label.text = title.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: title.startIndex..<title.index(title.startIndex, offsetBy: 1) )
```

Comment: I think for this example, you can use `title.indices.dropFirst()`

Comment: @Alexander índices it is not equivalent to Range<String.Index>. OP would need to create a range using the indices startIndex and endIndex

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a concise way to specify a `String` range.

You could make it a bit nicer with an extension:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func range(_ ir: Range<Int>) -> Range<String.Index> {
        return self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: ir.lowerBound) ..< self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: ir.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Then

```
title.startIndex..<title.index(title.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
```

becomes

```
title.range(0..<1)
```

**Note:** Be careful to specify a valid range, or this will crash, just like if you had used an offset beyond the end of your string in your example.

Comment: I was about to propose the same but extending String Protocol. Something like `extension StringProtocol {
    func range(_ start: Int, _ length: Int) -> Range<Index> { (index(startIndex, offsetBy: start, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? startIndex)..<(index(startIndex, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex) }
}`

Comment: That would make it a bit more general.  I'll do that if you don't mind.

Comment: I think I prefer to let them crash and burn for incorrectly specified ranges.

Comment: A general approach is proposed [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0265-offset-indexing-and-slicing.md) and currently [discussed](https://forums.swift.org/t/offset-indexing-and-slicing/28333) in the Swift forum.

Comment: @vacawama this would be extremely inefficient for large strings and you need a range from the end of it considering that you are offsetting both indices from the start. `func range(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        return start..<index(start, offsetBy: range.count)
    }`

Comment: @LeoDabus, you raise a good point.  I suppose the most efficient thing to do would be to look at the 3 offsets (first point from startIndex, first point to second point, second point to endIndex) and use the two smallest to establish the indices.

Comment: I don’t know if accessing the string count property (necessary for the calculations) would be efficient.

Comment: You could use the `indices` property, but the same concern applies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `replacingOccurrencesOf` is an Cocoa Objective-C NSString method, so you end up with type impedance mismatch between the String notion of a Range and the NSString notion of an NSRange. The simplest solution is to stay in the NSString world:

```
label.text = (title as NSString).replacingOccurrences(
    of: "\n", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, 
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
```

Otherwise I agree with vacawama's idea of an extension:

```
extension String {
    func range(_ start:Int, _ count:Int) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let i = self.index(start >= 0 ?
            self.startIndex :
            self.endIndex, offsetBy: start)
        let j = self.index(i, offsetBy: count)
        return i..<j
    }
    func nsRange(_ start:Int, _ count:Int) -> NSRange {
        return NSRange(self.range(start,count), in:self)
    }
}
```

Then you can say

```
label.text = title.replacingOccurrences(
    of: "\n", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, 
    range: title.range(0,2))
```

Comment: `String.Index` inside a String extension is redundant. Just `Index`